# R#6 - Suggests "Use directory" in razor views. How to disable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, resharper, resharper-6.0

I am using R#6 and when I edit some razor views, R#6 suggests that I "use directory".

(Whine :)) I dont want to! How do I turn off this annoyance? I have searched through R#6 options. It is definitely R# since the annoyance goes away when i suspend R#.

In the printscreen, R# wants to change /SignUp to ../Signup.

It is incorrect because the view is the layout and could be in any directory structure. So i want it to be /Signup

[image]

**Solution:** As derigel states.
Wait for the warning to show. Hit escape. Then CTRL+Enter. A mini menu appears where you can suppress or change the warning severity. I changed the warning severity to "do not show"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Valamas, OffBySome gave you really good advice, but you still able to disable this warning locally by comment or generally, at all. It's some UI problem here - first, press escape to disable popup, and then, press alt+enter and you will bring few options how to disable this warning.

Comment: Fantastic, now i can find how to turn any other annoyances off.

Answer (score 4):

For your url's, try using relative urls by using `@Url.Content("~/images/image.jpg")` and `@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")` instead of hard-coding the absolute / urls.  I think this will resolve the Resharper issue, and also make your url's relative in case you are hosting this as a subsite on an IIS instance.

Comment: This may have solved his specific problem but this is a real bug. You can see more information here. http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-273759. Too bad their not going to fix it. :(

Comment: Ha and funny that they link back here to the answer.

Comment: Bobby, we are going to fix this issue but more generally - by understanding MVC routing (there is linked issue for original issue - http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-225684). But, unfortunately, not in 6.1.

Comment: Anyway, I have gone back to R#5, too many issues. Will try again at 6.1.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by properly entering the path.

Original

```
    <Image Source="Images\Q_hor_pos_full_rgb.gif" Height="76" Margin="6,-3,0,7" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

It turns out that I had placed this xaml file in a subfolder, and that the Images folder was actually one level higher:

- Main\Images\Q_hor_pos_full_rgb.gif
- Main\UserControls\File.xaml

Fixed

```
    <Image Source="..\Images\Q_hor_pos_full_rgb.gif" Height="76" Margin="6,-3,0,7" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

As soon as I did that, the application found the file with no problem.