# How do I remove "Use Directory" message from ReSharper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, resharper

I just started a MVC3 Razor application and started typing out in one of the .cshtml files and I added an a tag with href, when I entered the location it keeps telling me to use a directory that it wants me to use. I cannot get rid of this and it is always visible.

Does anyone know what this feature is called and how to disable it either permanently or for certain files, either way is good. I tried looking through the options but with no luck.

Image:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576285/r6-suggests-use-directory-in-razor-views-how-to-disable

Comment: such an annoying 'feature' glad i know how to turn it off!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Go to ReSharper > Options > Code Inspection > Inspection Severity
2. Search for "path error" inspection
3. Set inspection severity to "Do not show"

Comment: This fixed the problem for me, thanks. Additional note for anyone using R#6, the exact location of this option is in ReSharper > Options > Code Inspection > Inspection Severity > Potential Code Quality issues > Path Error.

Comment: Thank you for this. My first instinct was to check here and I didn't - next time I trust those instincts! :)

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad I finally searched the web for how to get rid of that annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new feature for Resharper 6. I recently uninstalled it (rolled back to old) as it was causing 'out-of-memory' exceptions for me.

So, it may not be 100% on the spot but I think the feature you're looking for should be under `Coding Assistance |  Code Completion`.

If you cannot customize that specific option (which I think you can't) then the other option is turn off the whole `Code Analysis` thing.

IF this doesn't solve your problem, I'll try to find you an exact answer later.

Comment: Off topic: Have you tried profiling ReSharper memory usage according to [these guidelines](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Profiling+Instructions)? We're investigating every performance or memory consumption report. In fact, we've done a lot to reduce memory traffic ahead of R#6 release but apparently your case is special.